# Occasional 'The Token can't be used before...' error after Cognito authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, auth0

We are authenticating with AWS Cognito and using the resultant AccessToken for access to our Java API, which is using the Auth0 jwt library. We are occasionally seeing this error:

```
InvalidClaimException: The Token can't be used before <x>...
```

Where x is in the future, according to both our alerting software and our Slack instance where alerts are additionally sent to.

We've added an 'acceptLeeway' of 30seconds, which reduced the occurences but we're still occasionally seeing errors - x is now always 30 seconds in the future.

Beyond increasing the leeway further, any thoughts?

Comment: Are you syncing the clocks on the machines that you're using?  I'm guessing so given that it works most of the time.

Comment: It's an AWS server and we're not doing anything special, so yes I believe the clock is being sync'ed appropriately, and as you say, it works most of the time so wouldn't expect that much drift. I've checked the server time a couple of times and all looks well :/